# What is the best algorithm for face detection using opencv and raspberry camera module

Tags: opencv, camera, face-detection, raspberry-pi2, haar-classifier

i'm working on face and eye detection (no recognition needed) using opencv , and i've found some algorithms that i can use :

**Viola–Jones object detection framework** : This algorithm is implemented in OpenCV as cvHaarDetectObjects(). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework
**Local binary patterns (LBP)** is a type of feature used for classification in computer vision https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_binary_patterns
3.....

i'm just a newbie and i want to know what is the best algorithm (in term of speed and performance and precision ) for face and especially **eye detection** using opencv :) thanks a lot

update : for my situation i need to capture faces of people walking on a street from a distance of ~ 2-5 meters , i'm using raspberry pi 2 with opencv 3 gold and raspicam-0.1.3 libarrry for the pi camera module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience the best one is a Haarcascade. The file I use is haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml. I did many tests with all haar files and found that this one was the best.

```
std::vector<Rect> faces;
Mat img_gray;
Mat img; //here you have to load the image

CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
face_cascade.load("haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");

cvtColor( img, img_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
cv::equalizeHist( img_gray, img_gray );

int rect_size = 20;
float scale_factor = 1.05;
int min_neighbours = 1;
face_cascade.detectMultiScale( img_gray, faces, scale_factor, min_neighbours, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(rect_size, rect_size) );
```

The haar cascade returns several bounding box (they are the candidates). Some of these candidates will contain a face and other not. If most of the pixels of the bounding box are green, then probably there is no a face. You need to filter skin color pixels. You can do this with HSV. First you need to set a range, in our case this range only allow skin color pixels.

```
cv::Scalar  hsv_min = cv::Scalar(0, 30, 60);
cv::Scalar  hsv_max = cv::Scalar(20, 150, 255);
cvtColor(image, hsv_image, CV_BGR2HSV);
inRange (hsv_image, hsv_min, hsv_max, result_mask);
```

result_mask is a skin mask. All pixels in white are skin and all in black are not skin. Then you only need to count the number of white pixels in the mask:

```
int number_skin_pixels = cv::countNonZero(result_mask);
```

If there are many skin pixels, then youo can assume that there is a face. If not, then there is a false positive

Comment: ok thank you i have tried it ... have you any idea on how to optimize the code in facedetct.cpp because there is a lot of parameters ... i have also tested with lbpcascade_frontalface.xml. and it provide good detection ... for my situation i need to capture faces of people walking in a street

Comment: @user3530803 lpd is faster but less accurate than haar. I edited my answer to add some example you might need

Comment: @user3530803 The parameters scale_factor and min_neighbours are the keys to improve the accuracy. The values I put work very well if you look for a face in a not cluttered environment (like a picture of only one person). If you have many people in you image or a messy background you'll need to change a little these values

Comment: @user3530803 it also works fairly well if you add a color filter. Haar cascades only take into account gray scale image, so it could lead to false positives. If you filter the candidates by color you could reject those that are not skin color.

Comment: thanks you ... what can i do for filtering i have heared about a gaussian method is this right ??

Comment: What I do is to check the color. The haar cascade returns several bounding box (they are the candidates). Some of these candidates will contain a face and other not. If most of the pixels of the bounding box are green, then probably there is no a face. You need to filter skin color pixels. You can do this with HSV. I'll edit my answer en put some skin values

Comment: @user3530803 you should do different tests with the skin color range, it depends on the illumination and other variables

Comment: ok i will try it and tell you back thanks a  lot :)                                               i'm using the pi camera with opencv i have an issue here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315421/how-to-get-image-in-color-mode-using-opencv-c-with-raspberry-camera-module .. can you help

Comment: what parameters should i change to detect faces and eyes for many people : about 3 or 4 , thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

If you just need a face detector, Viola-Jones object detector is fast and very accurate. Haar cascade classifiers for eye detection are included in OpenCV.

LBP detector can be trained to recognise faces, too, but since you have no plans to use recognition, you can skip it.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV has recently added the **YuNet** face detection model to its library.

It is a very accurate model while still being lightweight to run at real-time speeds on CPU.

[yunet demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDocn.gif)

**Code:**

```
# Initialize detector
detector = cv2.FaceDetectorYN.create("face_detection_yunet_2022mar.onnx", "", (320, 320))
# Read image
img = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
# Get image shape
img_W = int(img.shape[1])
img_H = int(img.shape[0])
# Set input size
detector.setInputSize((img_W, img_H))
# Getting detections
detections = detector.detect(img)
```

Below is a comparison of other popular face-detection algorithms.

**Speed**

[Speed Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ImHI.png)

**Average Precision**

[AP Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T33NF.png)

[The Ultimate Face Detection Guide](https://learnopencv.com/what-is-face-detection-the-ultimate-guide/) - A detailed explanation and comparison of state-of-the-art face detection algorithms.

[Face Detection guide Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Di50FIoq8w)