# How to get image in color mode using opencv c++ with raspberry camera module

Tags: c++, opencv, colors, camera, raspberry-pi2

i'm using raspberry pi 2 with opencv 3 gold and raspicam-0.1.3 libarrry for the pi camera module 
I have test the code below and it worked but it provide for me an image in grayscale mode (black and white) but i want it in color mode (RGB)

here is the code :

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <raspicam/raspicam_cv.h>
using namespace std; 

int main ( int argc,char **argv ) {

    time_t timer_begin,timer_end;
    raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv Camera;
    cv::Mat image;
    int nCount=100;
    //set camera params
    Camera.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT, CV_8UC1 );
    //Open camera
    cout<<"Opening Camera..."<<endl;
    if (!Camera.open()) {cerr<<"Error opening the camera"<<endl;return -1;}
    //Start capture
    cout<<"Capturing "<<nCount<<" frames ...."<<endl;
    time ( &timer_begin );
    for ( int i=0; i<nCount; i++ ) {
        Camera.grab();
        Camera.retrieve ( image);
        if ( i%5==0 )  cout<<"\r captured "<<i<<" images"<<std::flush;
    }
    cout<<"Stop camera..."<<endl;
    Camera.release();
    //show time statistics
    time ( &timer_end ); /* get current time; same as: timer = time(NULL)  */
    double secondsElapsed = difftime ( timer_end,timer_begin );
    cout<< secondsElapsed<<" seconds for "<< nCount<<"  frames : FPS = "<<  ( float ) ( ( float ) ( nCount ) /secondsElapsed ) <<endl;
    //save image 
    cv::imwrite("raspicam_cv_image.jpg",image);
    cout<<"Image saved at raspicam_cv_image.jpg"<<endl;
}
```

just to notice that i get a colored image when trying the first example here : http://sourceforge.net/projects/raspicam/files/?source=navbar

what i did is to insert **cvtColor(image, cimg, CV_GRAY2RGB);** before imwrite but this didn't solve my problem

any help will be appreciated ... thanks

Comment: try changing `Camera.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT, CV_8UC1 );` to `Camera.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT, CV_8UC3 );`

Comment: =D this worked and without the need of cvtColor ... i will look for the doc  ... thanks a lot .

Comment: Nice, posting as an answer then, so other will find it more easily.

Comment: i have found that : CV_8UC3 means we use unsigned char types that are 8 bit long and each pixel has three of these to form the three channels : i think that 3 channels is for RGB because we have 3 colors is that right ??

Comment: exactly, 8UC1 means a 1 byte per color, i.e. gray image, while 8UC3 means 3 bytes per color, i.e. RGB image.

Answer (score 5):

You are setting your camera to "grayscale mode" here:

```
Camera.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT, CV_8UC1 );
```

If you want "colored mode", you shold do this instead:

```
Camera.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT, CV_8UC3 );
```

`CV_8UC1` means 1 byte per  color, i.e. grayscale, while `CV_8UC3` means 3 bytes per color, e.g. RGB

Comment: just to add :                                                                                                    A grayscale image has just one channel ==> CV_8UC1                           An RGB image has three channels: red, green, and blue ==> CV_8UC3

Comment: i have already reach more than 15 reputation so i'm marking it useful  now